# Translator vs Cell Decorator in hybris, which one is preferred in what situation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I know how to write and use `Cell Decorator` and `Translators` during `impex imports`

in hybris, However, I am not sure when the one is preferred over the other?

For example, I have used Cell Decorator to change the value of an attribute slightly like if a customer is from US I will append an '_US' at the end of customer number while inserting in the DB.
Similarly, I have used Translator when I need to find a status of a product Available/Out of stock based on product ID.

However, I am not 100% positive is this the only differentiation.

Any explanation with example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is a translator?

([from SAP documatentation](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/4ce7b82cbc574456ac197393f88e5cc6.html)):

> A translator class is a converter between ImpEx-related CSV files and values of attributes of Hybris Commerce items

The translator is a "converter" it is used when you need to modify your data into some other kind of data.

### What is a decorator?

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern))

> The decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class

### What should be used in hybris

For Impex most of the time you want to use a **translator** because you want to use simple syntax in the Impex file and **convert**( ie. translate/modify) it to the target format using code.

When you need to add functionality to an existing feature use a **decorator**. It can be used in Impex too if you want to **add** data.

For example you can read the Wikipedia article for decorator, in hybris you can look at `ChineseLogisticCellDecorator`. For translators, you have the list in hybris documentation (mentioned above)